# Magento translation package doesn't work well

Tags: php, magento, translation

After installing Magento , I downloaded a package for translation to Portuguese in [this link](http://mariosam.com.br/magento/traducao-magento/) and replaced the vendor folder for the content I downloaded . Even though I changed the language in my account to Portuguese and cleaned the cache, the translation was not satisfactory. Very little has been translated. The administrator area still has most of the elements in English. The contact us screen and user registration screen are still all in English! I tried to modify the files pt_BR.csv within i18n folders, but it does not seem to have any effect . How could I translate Magento screens effectively?

Comment: As I assume you understand Portugese, did you read http://mariosam.com.br/magento/falsa-traducao-magento/ ?

Comment: I know that the translation I downloaded is far from perfect, it's awful indeed. But, I would like to know how to create my own translation and why my adjustments in i18n files are not effective.